# Why do people vote much more readily on Meta than on other sites?

Tags: support, voting

I noticed that on Meta the vast majority of posts are either **heavily** upvoted or are considered preposterous and are **heavily** downvoted. Whereas, on other sites like Stack Overflow, the vast majority of posts are 0 scored, or have 1-2 upvotes or downvotes. To be fair, the other sites do have their fair share of heavily up/downvoted posts, but they seem to make up a much **much** smaller percentage of the total posts.

Why the disparity? Why are Meta users much more eager to click the up/downvote buttons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meta users are already generally invested in the network and reasonably familiar with the system. As such we have a larger proportion of active users who are involved in voting and other curation tasks.

With lesser post activity - we don't have that many questions per day, this translates to more votes

Comment: *'With lesser post activity - we don't have that many questions per day, this translates to more votes'* But what about sites (such as softwareengineering.SE) with moderate posts/day, but still most are 0 scored?

Comment: Well - basically everyone here is here for things to do with the SE network. People on other sites have more varying interests